# SDL 2 Requires Explicit Dependency Configuration and Boost Does Not

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, sdl-2

I am starting a new C++ project in Visual Studio 2015 that will include and link both the SDL 2 and Boost 1.6.0 libraries.  As expected, both require configuration of "Include Directories" and "Library Directories".  The SDL 2 library, however, also requires explicit inclusion in the "Additional Dependencies" setting of the linker; "SDL2.lib" and "SDL2main.lib".  Also, "SDL2.dll" has to be in the path or at the destination directory for builds to work.

Why is this?  Why does Boost find its library files automatically, where SDL requires so much additional configuration?

Comment: Boost uses a pragma for automatic linking. Also most of the boost libraries are header only so there is nothing to link. I would say most 3rd party libraries that I use (for medical imaging) do not use the pragma method that boost uses. However I use CMake so for the most part I do not deal with these settings in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you.  This explains it nicely.